# Disable Python requests SSL validation for an imported module

Tags: python, ssl, python-requests

I'm running a Python script that uses the `requests` package for making web requests. However, the web requests go through a proxy with a self-signed cert. As such, requests raise the following Exception:

`requests.exceptions.SSLError: ("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE', 'certificate verify failed')],)",)`

I know that SSL validation can be disabled in my own code by passing `verify=False`, e.g.: `requests.get("https://www.google.com", verify=False)`. I also know that if I had the certificate bundle, I could set the `REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE` or `CURL_CA_BUNDLE` environment variables to point to those files. However, I do not have the certificate bundle available.

How can I disable SSL validation for external modules without editing their code?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

**Note**: This solution is a complete hack.

**Short answer**: Set the `CURL_CA_BUNDLE` environment variable to an empty string.

Before:

```
$ python
import requests
requests.get('http://www.google.com')
<Response [200]>

requests.get('https://www.google.com')
...
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests-2.17.3-py2.7.egg/requests/adapters.py", line 514, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: ("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE', 'certificate verify failed')],)",)
```

After:

```
$ CURL_CA_BUNDLE="" python
import requests
requests.get('http://www.google.com')
<Response [200]>

requests.get('https://www.google.com')
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/urllib3-1.21.1-py2.7.egg/urllib3/connectionpool.py:852: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings InsecureRequestWarning)
<Response [200]>
```

**How it works**

This solution works because Python `requests` overwrites the default value for `verify` from the environment variables `CURL_CA_BUNDLE` and `REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE`, as can be seen [here](https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/8c211a96cdbe9fe320d63d9e1ae15c5c07e179f8/requests/sessions.py#L718):

```
if verify is True or verify is None:
verify = (os.environ.get('REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE') or
    os.environ.get('CURL_CA_BUNDLE'))
```

The environment variables are meant to specify the path to the certificate file or CA_BUNDLE and are copied into `verify`. However, by setting `CURL_CA_BUNDLE` to an empty string, the empty string is copied into `verify` and in Python, an empty string evaluates to `False`.

Note that this hack only works with the `CURL_CA_BUNDLE` environment variable - it does not work with the `REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE`. This is because `verify` [is set with the following statement](https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/8c211a96cdbe9fe320d63d9e1ae15c5c07e179f8/requests/sessions.py#L718):

`verify = (os.environ.get('REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE') or os.environ.get('CURL_CA_BUNDLE'))`

It only works with `CURL_CA_BUNDLE` because `'' or None` is not the same as `None or ''`, as can be seen below:

```
print repr(None or "")
# Prints: ''
print repr("" or None )
# Prints: None
```

Comment: I've successfully used this technique on Unix, but cannot get it to work on Windows

Comment: Have you tried `set CURL_CA_BUNDLE="" ` or `setx CURL_CA_BUNDLE="" ` on windows machine?

Comment: Also not on Mac :(

Comment: Also with `set CURL_CA_BUNDLE=""` not working on Windows for me

Comment: Interesting thing (in my case Linux Ubuntu): this works only if I start python command with `CURL_CA_BUNDLE=""` and in same line put `python`. 
It does not work if I put `CURL_CA_BUNDLE=""` and press `<Enter>` then call Python in next command line.

Comment: This is amazing in its simplicity and hackiness :) Confirming this works as described on macOS 10.14 with Python 3.7/3.8.

Comment: @David: That's how variables work in Bash and similar shells. If you just do `CURL_CA_BUNDLE=""`, that only sets the variable within the context of that specific shell or for the command that follows on the same line. If you use `export CURL_CA_BUNDLE=""`, then it will also apply to any new processes started from that shell, like Python (but still not ones in completely separate processes).

Comment: This no longer works with requests 2.28.0 or newer, since it was considered a bug, see https://github.com/psf/requests/issues/6071...

Answer (score 4):

I saw this hack only due to some trouble with my private CA.

The given hack with `CURL_CA_BUNDLE=''` will not longer work in 2022 with next `minor release` of requests (that means 2.28 ?).

Please refer to GH issue [6071](https://github.com/psf/requests/issues/6071) which was fixed 6 days before in Feb. 2022

Comment: Yeah... so are there any other hacks other than pinning the version of `requests`?

Comment: Use requests 2.27.0 (`pip install requests==2.27.0`)

Answer (score 2):

My problem was that a third party package sent the request, so that I had no chance to influence the `verify = True`.

What helped me:

```
pip install pip-system-certs
```

And then:

```
import pip_system_certs #import as first package
```

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me in Windows.