# SSL error while uploading python package to custom registry using twine

Tags: python-3.x, ssl, twine

When trying to upload a python custom package to our internal registry its failing with the following error.

```
 urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='custom-nexus.com’, port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /repository/pypi-internal/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')],)",),))
```

But the same url works fine when accessed through curl. Using curl -v option found that the ca-bundle used was in the location /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt

So tried providing this in the twine upload command using the --cert option. But then also its not working and failing with the same error.

```
twine upload --config-file .pypirc   --cert /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt  -r pypi dist/*
```

Python version used is 3.6. Please find below the list of library versions.

```
certifi==2020.4.5
setuptools==46.1.3
wheel==0.34.2
twine==3.1.1
pyOpenSSL==19.1.0
```

Answer (score 4):

For some reason it didnt work for me even after providing the certificate using --cert option. Might be some issue with the certificate. Then I came across the below hack to skip ssl verification in python requests library

[Disable Python requests SSL validation for an imported module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48391750/disable-python-requests-ssl-validation-for-an-imported-module)

(For anyone who doesn't know, TWINE under the hood also uses python requests library)

Following this, I tried the below command and it worked!

```
export CURL_CA_BUNDLE="" && twine upload ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I just posted on [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75870251/9587457) that setting `CURL_CA_BUNDLE` to an empty string doesn't seem to work anymore; but setting it to the .crt file itself does work for me. Granted, I had a cert that was working fine in the browser and probably via `curl` like in the OP example.

Answer (score 0):

The option to disable certificate verification was removed in requests==2.28.0 since it was considered a [bug](https://github.com/psf/requests/issues/6071).

A workaround therefore is to install requests==2.27.0 before pushing to the registry.

```
pip install requests==2.27.0     
export CURL_CA_BUNDLE="" && twine upload ...
```