# How to disable SSL certificate verification in Twine?

Tags: ssl-certificate, twine

When I tried to push a new package to my company's artifactory :

python -m twine upload --repository-url https:///artifactory/api/pypi/gdp_pypi dist/*

I got an error on SSL.
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:841)

Any way to disable the SSL verification?

Comment: Why not fix the error instead?

Comment: Yes you are right, I just point the variable REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE to my certificate and it worked.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disable Python requests SSL validation for an imported module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48391750/disable-python-requests-ssl-validation-for-an-imported-module)

Answer (score 2):

I just tried the solution by another post:
[Disable Python requests SSL validation for an imported module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48391750/disable-python-requests-ssl-validation-for-an-imported-module)

Simply setting environment variable CURL_CA_BUNDLE to an empty string did the job!

$ export CURL_CA_BUNDLE=""

Comment: This does not work anymore after the Bug https://github.com/psf/requests/issues/6071 was fixed

Answer (score 1):

Setting an empty string as suggested above doesn't seem to work anymore:

```
$ export CURL_CA_BUNDLE=""
```

BUT, when I navigated to my organization's Github in the browser (where the cert was installed and working) and downloaded the `.crt` for the first cert in the chain, then it DID work when setting the variable to that `.crt` file.

```
$ export CURL_CA_BUNDLE="/path/to/cert.crt"
```

Answer (score 0):

The workaround using `CURL_CA_BUNDLE` described in "[Disable Python requests SSL validation for an imported module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48391750/disable-python-requests-ssl-validation-for-an-imported-module)" doesn't work anymore.

Possible solution is to use separate script which could be named `twine-trusted` containing the following code:

```py
import twine.__main__


def disable_server_certificate_validation():
    "Allow twine to just trust the hosts"
    twine.repository.Repository.set_certificate_authority = lambda *args, **kwargs: None


def main():
    disable_server_certificate_validation()
    twine.__main__.main()

__name__ == '__main__' and main()
```

Source: https://github.com/pypa/twine/pull/463#issuecomment-556892003